# How to translate a qsort from C to Java?

Tags: java, c, compare, translate, qsort

I'm a fairly new coder. I'm trying to understand the following **C** code:

```
int compar (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return ((int *) a)[0] - ((int *) b)[0];
}
```

that is used in:

```
qsort (&tree[0][0], 8, 3 * sizeof (int), &compar);
```

the tree is a 2D array that's specifically an 8x3 for this case (it gets filled with possible moves, but I think that's irrelevant for the purpose of learning this). I understand the first three parameters of qsort (though a bit iffy as to why the first one calls the address but I think that's just how C calls the array), but not the fourth. I don't understand how qsort is using compar. I want to design a **Java** sorting method that does same as the aforementioned qsort, though I don't really care for it to be quick sort per se (as in I'm free to utilize whatever Java may offer and it doesn't have to be a quick sort. Because this isn't an assignment, I just want a sorting method that can sort fast so a nlogn or something would be helpful as this project involves a lot of recursion and calls this a lot of times). I'm struggling to understand what the compar is doing and then how qsort utilizes that to sort.

```
unorderStart
 0     -2      1 
 0     -1      2 
 5      1      2 
 5      2      1 
 0      2     -1 
 0      1     -2 
 0     -1     -2 
 0     -2     -1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -2      1 
 0     -1      2 
 0      2     -1 
 0      1     -2 
 0     -1     -2 
 0     -2     -1 
 5      1      2 
 5      2      1 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -1      3 
 1      0      4 
 3      2      4 
 3      3      3 
 3      3      1 
 3      2      0 
 0      0      0 
 0     -1      1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -1      3 
 0      0      0 
 0     -1      1 
 1      0      4 
 3      2      4 
 3      3      3 
 3      3      1 
 3      2      0 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -2      5 
 0     -1      6 
 0      1      6 
 0      2      5 
 5      2      3 
 0      1      2 
 0     -1      2 
 0     -2      3 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -2      5 
 0     -1      6 
 0      1      6 
 0      2      5 
 0      1      2 
 0     -1      2 
 0     -2      3 
 5      2      3 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      0      4 
 0      1      5 
 0      3      5 
 1      4      4 
 3      4      2 
 2      3      1 
 3      1      1 
 3      0      2 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      0      4 
 0      1      5 
 0      3      5 
 1      4      4 
 2      3      1 
 3      4      2 
 3      1      1 
 3      0      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      2      5 
 0      3      6 
 0      5      6 
 0      6      5 
 0      6      3 
 0      5      2 
 5      3      2 
 0      2      3 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      2      5 
 0      3      6 
 0      5      6 
 0      6      5 
 0      6      3 
 0      5      2 
 0      2      3 
 5      3      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 3      1      3 
 2      2      4 
 0      4      4 
 0      5      3 
 0      5      1 
 1      4      0 
 2      2      0 
 2      1      1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      4      4 
 0      5      3 
 0      5      1 
 1      4      0 
 2      2      4 
 2      2      0 
 2      1      1 
 3      1      3 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 4      2      1 
 0      3      2 
 0      5      2 
 0      6      1 
 0      6     -1 
 0      5     -2 
 0      3     -2 
 0      2     -1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      3      2 
 0      5      2 
 0      6      1 
 0      6     -1 
 0      5     -2 
 0      3     -2 
 0      2     -1 
 4      2      1 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 2      0      2 
 2      1      3 
 2      3      3 
 2      4      2 
 0      4      0 
 0      3     -1 
 0      1     -1 
 0      0      0 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      4      0 
 0      3     -1 
 0      1     -1 
 0      0      0 
 2      0      2 
 2      1      3 
 2      3      3 
 2      4      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -2      3 
 0     -1      4 
 2      1      4 
 0      2      3 
 0      2      1 
 2      1      0 
 0     -1      0 
 0     -2      1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -2      3 
 0     -1      4 
 0      2      3 
 0      2      1 
 0     -1      0 
 0     -2      1 
 2      1      4 
 2      1      0 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -1      5 
 0      0      6 
 0      2      6 
 0      3      5 
 1      3      3 
 7      2      2 
 0      0      2 
 0     -1      3 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -1      5 
 0      0      6 
 0      2      6 
 0      3      5 
 0      0      2 
 0     -1      3 
 1      3      3 
 7      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      1      4 
 0      2      5 
 0      4      5 
 0      5      4 
 0      5      2 
 2      4      1 
 0      2      1 
 0      1      2 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      1      4 
 0      2      5 
 0      4      5 
 0      5      4 
 0      5      2 
 0      2      1 
 0      1      2 
 2      4      1 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 6      2      2 
 0      3      3 
 0      5      3 
 0      6      2 
 0      6      0 
 0      5     -1 
 0      3     -1 
 1      2      0 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      3      3 
 0      5      3 
 0      6      2 
 0      6      0 
 0      5     -1 
 0      3     -1 
 1      2      0 
 6      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 2      0      1 
 0      1      2 
 0      3      2 
 0      4      1 
 0      4     -1 
 0      3     -2 
 0      1     -2 
 0      0     -1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      1      2 
 0      3      2 
 0      4      1 
 0      4     -1 
 0      3     -2 
 0      1     -2 
 0      0     -1 
 2      0      1 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -2      2 
 0     -1      3 
 1      1      3 
 5      2      2 
 0      2      0 
 0      1     -1 
 0     -1     -1 
 0     -2      0 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -2      2 
 0     -1      3 
 0      2      0 
 0      1     -1 
 0     -1     -1 
 0     -2      0 
 1      1      3 
 5      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -1      4 
 0      0      5 
 0      2      5 
 2      3      4 
 0      3      2 
 0      2      1 
 0      0      1 
 0     -1      2 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -1      4 
 0      0      5 
 0      2      5 
 0      3      2 
 0      2      1 
 0      0      1 
 0     -1      2 
 2      3      4 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      1      5 
 0      2      6 
 0      4      6 
 0      5      5 
 0      5      3 
 1      4      2 
 4      2      2 
 0      1      3 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      1      5 
 0      2      6 
 0      4      6 
 0      5      5 
 0      5      3 
 0      1      3 
 1      4      2 
 4      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      2      3 
 0      3      4 
 0      5      4 
 0      6      3 
 0      6      1 
 0      5      0 
 2      3      0 
 0      2      1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      2      3 
 0      3      4 
 0      5      4 
 0      6      3 
 0      6      1 
 0      5      0 
 0      2      1 
 2      3      0 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 1      1      1 
 3      2      2 
 0      4      2 
 0      5      1 
 0      5     -1 
 0      4     -2 
 0      2     -2 
 0      1     -1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      4      2 
 0      5      1 
 0      5     -1 
 0      4     -2 
 0      2     -2 
 0      1     -1 
 1      1      1 
 3      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -1      2 
 2      0      3 
 0      2      3 
 0      3      2 
 0      3      0 
 0      2     -1 
 0      0     -1 
 0     -1      0 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -1      2 
 0      2      3 
 0      3      2 
 0      3      0 
 0      2     -1 
 0      0     -1 
 0     -1      0 
 2      0      3 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -2      4 
 0     -1      5 
 0      1      5 
 1      2      4 
 2      2      2 
 0      1      1 
 0     -1      1 
 0     -2      2 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -2      4 
 0     -1      5 
 0      1      5 
 0      1      1 
 0     -1      1 
 0     -2      2 
 1      2      4 
 2      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      0      5 
 0      1      6 
 0      3      6 
 0      4      5 
 2      4      3 
 0      3      2 
 0      1      2 
 0      0      3 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      0      5 
 0      1      6 
 0      3      6 
 0      4      5 
 0      3      2 
 0      1      2 
 0      0      3 
 2      4      3 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      2      4 
 0      3      5 
 0      5      5 
 0      6      4 
 0      6      2 
 0      5      1 
 1      3      1 
 1      2      2 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      2      4 
 0      3      5 
 0      5      5 
 0      6      4 
 0      6      2 
 0      5      1 
 1      3      1 
 1      2      2 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0      1      2 
 0      2      3 
 0      4      3 
 0      5      2 
 0      5      0 
 0      4     -1 
 0      2     -1 
 1      1      0 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0      1      2 
 0      2      3 
 0      4      3 
 0      5      2 
 0      5      0 
 0      4     -1 
 0      2     -1 
 1      1      0 
orderEnd

unorderStart
 0     -1      1 
 0      0      2 
 0      2      2 
 0      3      1 
 0      3     -1 
 0      2     -2 
 0      0     -2 
 0     -1     -1 
unorderEnd
orderStart
 0     -1      1 
 0      0      2 
 0      2      2 
 0      3      1 
 0      3     -1 
 0      2     -2 
 0      0     -2 
 0     -1     -1 
orderEnd
```

I think that the first column is sorted in a descending fashion, but what is happening to the other two columns? The rows? The Java code doesn't have to utilize generics or anything, as a matter a fact, the simpler the code, the better. Any help would be appreciated and if you would, please explain the code? Thanks

Comment: it's returning the difference between `a` and `b`. `((int *)a)` casts `a` to an int pointer, the array syntax `[0]` is dereferencing that pointer to get an int. It could be rewritten as `*((int *)a);`

Comment: I get that a and b would be the first column elements, but I don't understand its implementation. How comes the other two columns also change?

Comment: Post the java code you have written so far.

Comment: In regards to `nlogn` sort, you can also try Heapsort and Mergesort.

Comment: From my experience, it is not a good idea to "translate" from one language to another "directly". Use the Algorithm behind the code and implement it in the target language. The source lang may use constructs and methodologies that are not applicable in the target lang. Especially with C code, there may already be loads of code you can use from the java libs that are boilerplate code in C.

Comment: Isn't there any read-to-use Java sort library? Google gives lots of hits.

Comment: Okay, so I understand that I may not be able to copy qsort exactly, but I'm mostly struggling to grasp the concept of how C code is using the compar. Once I understand that how the qsort is using compar, I can write the rest. I can transpose the array and sort the first row and retranspose to get the first column sorted (I don't think that'll take too long), but I dont understand what happens to the rest of the array. I don't Know if I'm clear enough, but sometimes I see the the second and third column swap numbers or swap with another row? If you could just explain that part please

Comment: The comparator usage for `qsort` is fairly simple. When you invoke qsort you give it (a) a base address, (b) a number of elements, (c) a width (or stride) or each element in *bytes*, and finally (d) a comparison function. From that point, all qsort does is calculate address offsets from the base address and element width you provided to generate the address of each "element" being sorted, Those addresses are then passed to your comparator as `const void*`. It is up to you to ensure the casts *back* to proper element pointer types for proper comparison is done in your comparator function.

Comment: @WhozCraig I like how you explained the offsetting, but my question is exactly how d is being used. In the code I posted, I think that I might not understand the comparison method I posted very well either.
'
public int comparer(int a[], int b[]){
 int val1 = a[0];
 int val2 = b[0];
        return compar(val1-val2);
    }
    public compar(int a){
 if(a>0)
     return 1;
 if(a<0)
     return -1;
 return 0;
    }'

Comment: And note that width in bytes from (c) is not only used for the address of each element being sorted, it is also used by qsort to know how many bytes to swap around when swapping elements. In your case, each element is itself an array of three `int`, so that width is paramount as the third parameter. It would probably help you understand more if your arguments were correct (they're not, but they happened to work), and your pointer work in your comparator was reflective of the underlying data (again, its not, but happens to work in your case). [See this full example](http://ideone.com/N60koc).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I generally define the cmp with parameters of pointers to the appropriate type. Calling qsort with that for `void *` is OK. Then there is no need to cast it back in cmp: `int compar (const mytype *a, const mytype *b)` and `qsort(...., compar)`. What would be wrong with that?

Comment: In Java you would insert the array elements into a container that provides sorted access to its values (for example `java.util.TreeSet`) and provide it with an appropriate comparator. Do **NOT** try to implement a sorting algorithm on your own.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it wouldn't be conformant to the standard as `qsort` is documented, which specifically states the parameters are to be `const void*` It isn't that big a deal to just do the proper casts (and retain const-ness, which more often than not is the biggest faux pas in most people's comparators).

Comment: @WhozCraig, wouldn't `void *` be compatible with any (const) pointer type? Documenting `void *` in `qsort` is of course abstraction hiding, or is C now being stripped of abstraction hiding?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it isn't a question of whether `void*` and `something*` are compatible. It's a *type* thing, and the pointer types aren't the thing I'm talking about. The *function pointer type* is what I refer to . `int (*cmp)(const void*,const void*);` is a different *type* than `int (*cmp)(something* something*)`. The only way the latter is passed to `qsort` is via a cast, and if you're going to cast, why not just do it where the library designers intended in the first place, namely in the comparator where it belongs.

Comment: The only reason you'd implement quicksort in Java is for practice. There is the Collections.sort() method to handle this; quicksort for primitives and mergesort for objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I did some tests (VC2008, pre C99) and the compiler handles it well. Yes they are different types, but are they _compatible_ types? `qsort`, after all, will call cmp with two pointers to "things that qsort doesnt know about" but that cmp fully understands.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Ok, I'll put it this way. Writing conforming code will, per the standard, *work*. A compliant C compiler will puke when sending a function pointer of an improper type to `qsort`. The only way to squelch that without changing the function is to introduce a cast at the `qsort` call-point, in effect, *lying* to `qsort`. It *seems* to work. Now, some neophyte comes along two years later, wants to use that comparator for some nefarious deed of their own, and changes the signature (adds another parameter). The code still compiles because of the cast. Oops. Moral: write compliant code.

Comment: Collections.sort() only works on lists afaik, and the tree 2D array is full of ints.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Arrays.sort can use a comparator that the coder can customize. Note this is basically the end product I made based off of mostly everything commented (everything that attempted to help me understand at least). Thanks so much!

```
public static void reorder(int[][] a){
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final int[] a, final int[] b) {
         Integer c = Integer.valueOf(a[0]);
         Integer d = Integer.valueOf(b[0]);
        return c.compareTo(d);
    }
    });
}
```